# Fatal: not a git repository - after BSoD

Tags: windows, git

I was committing and then my Windows ( .. :( ) machine crashed and presented me with the lovely and infamous Blue Screen of Death. I rebooted and went right back to work, only to discover that something's seriously wrong with my local git repo.

"Fatal: not a git repository"

... Well, that escalated quickly.

I've been reading up on this issue (also here on StackOverflow), but haven't found a solution yet. The things I did include:

- git init (says within 0.1s: *Reinitialized existing Git repository*)
- git status (gives same fatal error)
- git push origin develop (same fatal error)

The .git folder is still there and looks normal (although I wouldn't directly spot any anomalies).

It looks like there's nothing I can do on the command line to revive my repository.

I have found [this reference](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Having-an-invalid-HEAD-file-causes-git-not-to-recognize-the-repository-td7565135.html), but I have no idea how to "change HEAD to a valid ref/hash".

Is there anyone who knows where to go from here?

(I know this questions shows up multiple times on SO, but none of those problems have the same origin and their solutions don't work. Please be sure this question really is a duplicate if you mark it as such.)

Comment: If the stuff you were committing is not too complex, maybe you could just make a new clone of the origin repository, carry your local changes over to that repo and continue working from there?

Comment: That sure is an option, although I am pretty curious to know how to fix this 'the right way'. :)

Comment: you can delete the .git folder if you have a clone somewhere (e.g. on github), then re-init your local folder, and pull from the other repository.

Comment: what gives `git fsck`?

Comment: What is in the ".git/HEAD" file? Can it be opened?

Comment: With Notepad++ I saw something like NULL NULL NULL NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm the asker.)

Unfortunately I didn't have the time to solve this problem in time. The pressure in this project is on and I needed to continue. I decided to do a complete new checkout. Everything works fine again.

Lesson learned: never get a BSoD while committing.

Comment: Shouldn't the lesson be "make more frequent backups"?

Comment: Maybe you could also have written something like "ref: refs/heads/master" to `.git/HEAD` to make it be detectable as Git repository again. On my system I can make a Git repository manually just by creating 2 empty directories ("objects" and "refs") and one little file HEAD with `ref: refs/heads/something` content.

Comment: @CharlesB no, I didn't lose anything. I pushed minutes earlier as well.

Comment: @Sherlock Good for you!

Comment: @Vi. - Thanks! Rewriting the .git/HEAD file to the last branch I worked on saved me a lot of trouble! Thanks again!

Comment: There appears to be a git bug causing a bluescreen on ssh pushes.

Comment: Thanks - saved me the time of breaking my head on it - exactly the same scenario (BSOD on push) happened

Comment: Victim of BSOD and same situation. Eventually I backed up my code, emptied my repository, cloned again, put the backed up code back in the repository. Github detected whitespace changes in every file, so I went on and committed ONLY the Whitespace changed files.
Now I am working as I was supposed to, however now my commit log contains a commit that is all about whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this in the future:

Ran into this issue today, BSoD followed by git no recognizing I was in a git repo.
In my case .git/HEAD had become just null characters which is why git didn't recognize the directory as a git repo. If this is also the case for you try running:

**echo 'ref: refs/heads/main' >.git/HEAD**

This is just overwriting the current contents of .git/HEAD with a valid head which can be the head to any branch head file listed in the .git/refs/heads directory. Once .git/HEAD is valid, git should instantly recognize that your in a git repo again.